# Specializing a templated overriden function / Avoid object slicing

Tags: c++, c++11

I have started to write some classes to compute the transformation along a kinematic chain. I'm having a templated parent class `KinematicChainSegment` and multiple specialized implementations of it (e.g. for revolute or prismatic joints). To give a concrete, minimum example - this how I would like it to look:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template<typename T>
class KinematicChainSegment {
    public:
        KinematicChainSegment() {};
        virtual ~KinematicChainSegment() {};

        virtual Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 4> getTransformationMatrix() const = 0;
        virtual KinematicChainSegment<T> inverse() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class StaticLink : public KinematicChainSegment<T> {
    public:
        StaticLink(const Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 4>& transformation = Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 4>::Identity())
        : KinematicChainSegment<T>(),
          _transformationMatrix(transformation) {
        }

        virtual ~StaticLink() {};

        virtual Eigen::Matrix<T,4,4> getTransformationMatrix() const override {
            return _transformationMatrix;
        }

        virtual StaticLink<T> inverse() const override {
            return StaticLink<T>(_transformationMatrix.inverse());
        }

    protected:
        Eigen::Matrix<T,4,4> _transformationMatrix;
};
```

However, when compiling this example I get the `error: invalid abstract return type ‘KinematicChainSegment<T>’`, and changing the return type of `StaticLink<T>::inverse()` to `KinematicChainSegment<T>` results in `error: invalid abstract return type ‘KinematicChainSegment<T>’`, so I ended up with the following piece of code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class KinematicChainSegment {
    public:
        KinematicChainSegment() {};
        virtual ~KinematicChainSegment() {};

        virtual Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 4> getTransformationMatrix() const {
            std::cout << "Calling KinematicChainSegment<T>::getTransformationMatrix(). This method should be overwritten by any derivative class." << std::endl;
            return Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 4>::Identity();
        }

        virtual KinematicChainSegment<T> inverse() const {
            std::cout << "Calling KinematicChainSegment<T>::inverse(). This method should be overwritten by any derivative class." << std::endl;
            return KinematicChainSegment<T>();
        };
};

template<typename T>
class StaticLink : public KinematicChainSegment<T>   {
    public:
        StaticLink(const Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 4>& transformation = Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 4>::Identity())
        : KinematicChainSegment<T>(),
          _transformationMatrix(transformation) {
        }

        virtual ~StaticLink() {};

        virtual Eigen::Matrix<T,4,4> getTransformationMatrix() const override {
            return _transformationMatrix;
        }

        virtual KinematicChainSegment<T> inverse() const override {
            return StaticLink<T>(_transformationMatrix.inverse());
        }

    protected:
        Eigen::Matrix<T,4,4> _transformationMatrix;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Eigen::Matrix<float,4,4> transform;
    transform << 1, 0, 0, 1,
                 0, 1, 0, 2,
                 0, 0, 1, 3,
                 0, 0, 0, 1;

    KinematicChainSegment<float> link = StaticLink<float>(transform);
    std::cout << "link: " << link.getTransformationMatrix() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "inverse link: " << link.inverse().getTransformationMatrix() << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately this comes now with a bunch of object slicing issues, as you can see on the programs output below:

```
link: Calling KinematicChainSegment<T>::getTransformationMatrix(). This method should be overwritten by any derivative class.
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
inverse link: Calling KinematicChainSegment<T>::inverse(). This method should be overwritten by any derivative class.
Calling KinematicChainSegment<T>::getTransformationMatrix(). This method should be overwritten by any derivative class.
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

I guess I might have a too Java-like understanding of object inheritance...
What is the best practice to resolve an issue like this? From what I found so far it seems that the only option is to use pointers both, all return types and the used object instances... Or is there any other way of making this work?

Comment: `virtual KinematicChainSegment<T> inverse() const = 0;` this is wrong, you can't return abstract class object as a value! This mistake indicates that it is to early for you to write own advanced templates.

Comment: If you need abstraction as a return type or parameter it must be a pointer (preferably smart) or reference. I relay recommend you to go back to good C++ handbook, since this is a basics of polymorphism in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you are using your knowledge of Java to reason about C++ will get you into no end of trouble, since they are actually quite different languages.

You have encountered trouble this time because Java uses reference semantics by default, and C++ uses value semantics.   Returning by value from a function means (apart from cases of elision, which I won't expand on) constructing an instance of the returned type - which is impossible for an abstract class.  Returning by value also causes the object slicing you see when you make the base non-abstract.

To fix the problem in C++, it is necessary to use a pointer in some form - preferably a smart pointer.    I'll provide an option using the templated class `std::unique_ptr` (in standard header `<memory>`).    This only works for C++11 and later (since it was C++11 that introduced `unique_ptr`).

Firstly, change the return type of `inverse()`

```
template<typename T>
class KinematicChainSegment
{
    public:
        // other member functions omitted
    virtual std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> > inverse() const = 0;
};
```

then override it in a derived class

```
template<typename T>
class StaticLink : public KinematicChainSegment<T>
{
    public:

    virtual std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> > inverse() const override;


    protected:
        Eigen::Matrix<T,4,4> _transformationMatrix;
};
```

Note that the return type of the overridden `inverse()` remains the same as in the base class.  Changing the return type to `std::unique_ptr<StaticLink<T> >` will not work - even though `StaticLink<T>` is derived from `KinematicChainSegment<T>`, the class `std::unique_ptr<StaticLink<T> >` is not actually derived from `std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> >`.

Although defining (implementing) this function inline is possible, I'll define the function out of line for ease of explanation.

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> > StaticLink<T>::inverse() const
{
     return std::make_unique<StaticLink<T> >(_transformationMatrix.inverse());
}
```

This call of `std::make_unique()` has the effect of constructing a `std::unique_ptr<StaticLink<T> >` that manages an object created from `_transformationMatrix.inverse()`.

This works since `std::unique_ptr` does support implicit conversions.   `StaticLink<T>` inherits from `KinematicChainSegment<T>` so conversion of `std::unique_ptr<StaticLink<T> >` to `std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> >` is valid - despite the fact that there is no inheritance relationship between them.

The above does means that the caller will receive a `KinematicChainSegment<T>`, and can then use the managed polymorphically.   For example;

```
  int main()
  {
       StaticLink<T>  static_link;

       // presumably set state of the object static_link here

       std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> >  clone = static_link.inverse();

       //  Use virtual functions of clone

       std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> > clone_inverse = clone->inverse();

  }
```

In this case, `clone` is a `std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> >`  that manages a pointer to a `StaticLink<T>`.    The call of `clone->inverse()` is therefore polymorphic, and will also return a `std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T> >`  that manages a pointer to a `StaticLink<T>`.

If you design correctly (as with any form of inheritance, whether involving templated classes or not) `main()` should not need to have hard-coded knowledge of the class `StaticLink` at all, since the calls of member functions will be polymorphic (resolve to type of the actual contained object).

It is possible to also use raw (not smart pointers).   There are numerous down sides of doing that, so I won't demonstrate that.

The above is (I presume) more complicated than you expected when mixing use of templates with inheritance.    I would strongly advise not mixing templates with inheritance until you have learned significantly more about each (independently).

Also, coming back to my opening comment.   If you want to learn C++, don't try to map your knowledge of Java into C++.   Java and C++ are actually quite different languages, even if their syntax is similar, and the way they work is quite different.   You'll actually need to unlearn quite a few techniques that are popular in Java because they simply won't work as you expect in C++.   (Similarly, someone learning Java based on knowledge of C++ will run into problems, because quite a few techniques do not carry across).

Comment: So, wrapping the whole thing in a [PImpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) it is... Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: I'm not referring to the pimpl idiom.    Although smart pointers and pimpls have some characteristics in common, they are quite different and meet different purposes.

Comment: I got where you were heading. ;-) I just prefer to hide the whole smart-pointer wrapping from the "user".

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return an object of an abstract class by value. The problem is unrelated to using templates.

In C++ you need either a pointer or a reference for inheritance based polymorphism to work.

A simple solution would be to make `inverse` return a `std::unique_ptr<KinematicChainSegment<T>>` and use `std::make_unique` in the overriden functions.

This solution may not be ideal if you often use the object in a non-polymorphic way - as presented in your example - because it causes an unnecessary allocation and `B bf = *b.inverse()` would be required which makes a copy.

It is possible however to preserve both interfaces.

```
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> f() const {
        return this->f_impl();
    }

protected:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> f_impl() const = 0;
};

struct B : A
{
    B f(int = 0) const // additional parameter so it doesn't collide with A::f
    {
        return B{};
    }

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<A> f_impl() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<B>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::unique_ptr<A> b = std::make_unique<B>();
        std::unique_ptr<A> bf = b->f();
        (void)bf;
    }

    {
        B b{};
        B bf = b.f();
        (void)bf;
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8a2423461eb8d84

This returns by value if the type is known at compile time, and by a `std::unique_ptr` if accessed through a base class. This can easly be extended to inheritance hierarchies of higher depth, the only issue is non-covariance of `std::unique_ptr` but there are answered questions regarding that on the site.

Comment: Just noticed that `std::make_unique` is a C++14 feature.

Comment: you can easly make one yourself in C++11.